# How to incorporate ELMo into the simple classification of AllenNLP Guide

Tags: python, allennlp, elmo

I am a beginner and not a native English speaker, so I may ask poor questions.Sorry!

I recently finished the official AllenNLP tutorial(https://guide.allennlp.org/training-and-prediction) and want to **change the simple classifier's word embedding to ELMo.**

Also, I want to **make the architecture of the simple classifier more complex** to increase its accuracy.
I think I'm done with the implementation of the model.

**simple_classifier.py**

```
@Model.register("simple_classifier")
class SimpleClassifier(Model):
    def __init__(
        self, vocab: Vocabulary, embedder: TextFieldEmbedder, encoder: Seq2VecEncoder
    ):
        super().__init__(vocab)
        self.embedder = embedder
        self.encoder = encoder
        num_labels = vocab.get_vocab_size("labels")
        self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.layer1=torch.nn.Linear(encoder.get_output_dim(),512)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Linear(512, 128)
        self.layer3 = torch.nn.Linear(128, 50)
        self.layer4 = torch.nn.Linear(50, 10)
        self.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(10, num_labels)
        self.accuracy = CategoricalAccuracy()

    def forward(
        self, text: TextFieldTensors, label: torch.Tensor = None
    ) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        # Shape: (batch_size, num_tokens, embedding_dim)
        embedded_text = self.embedder(text)
        # Shape: (batch_size, num_tokens)
        mask = util.get_text_field_mask(text)
        # Shape: (batch_size, encoding_dim)
        encoded_text = self.encoder(embedded_text, mask)
        x=self.relu(self.layer1(encoded_text))
        x=self.relu(self.layer2(x))
        x=self.relu(self.layer3(x))
        x=self.relu(self.layer4(x))
        # Shape: (batch_size, num_labels)
        logits = self.classifier(x)
        # Shape: (batch_size, num_labels)
        probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(logits)
        # Shape: (1,)
        output = {"probs": probs}
        if label is not None:
            self.accuracy(logits, label)
            output["loss"] = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(logits, label)
        return output

    def get_metrics(self, reset: bool = False) -> Dict[str, float]:
        return {"accuracy": self.accuracy.get_metric(reset)}
```

But I have no idea how to change the configuration file.
How do I change the following configuration file in the official tutorial to use ELMo?

**my_text_classifier.jsonnet**

```
{
    "dataset_reader" : {
        "type": "classification-tsv",
        "token_indexers": {
            "tokens": {
                "type": "single_id"
            }
        }
    },
    "train_data_path": "data/movie_review/train.tsv",
    "validation_data_path": "data/movie_review/dev.tsv",
    "model": {
        "type": "simple_classifier",
        "embedder": {
            "token_embedders": {
                "tokens": {
                    "type": "embedding",
                    "embedding_dim": 10
                }
            }
        },
        "encoder": {
            "type": "bag_of_embeddings",
            "embedding_dim": 10
        }
    },
    "data_loader": {
        "batch_size": 8,
        "shuffle": true
    },
    "trainer": {
        "optimizer": "adam",
        "num_epochs": 5
    }
}
```

I'm very happy if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the way the BiDAF model uses ELMo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/allenai/allennlp-models/main/training_config/rc/bidaf_elmo.jsonnet

You can steal some of the components of that config. You will need the token embedder under the name `"elmo"`, and, I believe, both the token indexers under `"tokens"` and `"elmo"`.

It should work without having to write any code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 

Thank you very much!! Maybe I could have implemented it.

I have one more question. Is there a way to check if the embedded expressions in the text are mostly correct? (For example, by extracting the embedding vectors of similar sentences and calculating the cosine similarity.)

Comment: There is no built-in way to check for correctness, but what you suggest makes sense. Note that ELMo is not deterministic, and might give you different answers each time you run it. In particular, it likes to be warmed up with a few sequences to make the answers more stable.

Comment: I'll try it! Thank you very much. I'm very grateful for your help!